# 'mettila' o 'mettilala'

Tags: verbs, pronouns

Se dico a qualcuno di mettere un cosa lì, posso dire:

> mettila lì

se invece dico a qualcuno di fascicolare una carta in un certo posto, dico:

> fascicolala lì

Domanda: In analogia con 'fascicolala lì', posso dire 'mettilala lì'?

Se sì, perché? e se no, perché no?

Comment: Che c'entravano le preposizioni?

Comment: @dag, avevo confuso le preposizioni con i pronomi ;)

Comment: Esiste un verbo transitivo "alare" nel gergo nautico: "tirare", detto di cavi. Quindi, volendo indicare al mozzo dove tirare in secco una scialuppa, può dirgli: "àlala là" :)

Answer (score 12):

Nel caso di "fascicolala" il verbo è "fascicolare", imperativo "fascicola" + pronome "la", risultato "fascicolala".

Nel caso di "mettila" il verbo è "mettere", imperativo "metti" + pronome "la", risultato "mettila".

Se esistesse un verbo "mettilare" (il che non mi risulta, e in ogni caso credo avrebbe un altro significato), potresti dire "mettilala".

(Naturalmente esiste "mettila là", ma in questo caso non c'entra assolutamente nulla.)